# Number of occurrences in a text file where first character after 12th pipe is equal to 1?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am fairly new to regular expressions and am looking for a sed/awk/grep/wc command to find the following in a pipe delimited text file the number of occurrences of the digit 1 after the 12th pipe.

Here is an example of the text file:

```
2|JOHN||HAY||2955|ROSE|ST|#39D|Tool|TX|769065589|2542444320|||2222299310|SSD||01/08/2014^M
8|ALEN|BOBRISE|FITZGERALD||5432|Red|Ave|Apt 253|Bloomington|MN|559322972||9582544754|||MINNESOTA JIL|MN|01/08/2014^M
```

My preferance is sed or wc since this is what I am most familiar with, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: Do you mean _field_ 12 or 13? Because neither of your fields have that in them. Or do you mean 'any field >12'?

Comment: Depends on whether you are counting starting at 0 or 1. First character after the 12th pipe.  I've figured it out now.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have 11 after the 12th pipe, does that count as 0, 1, or 2 occurrences of 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `cut`

```
cat myfile.txt | cut -d '|' -f 12 | grep -c 1
```

Comment: Going with this based on your suggestion: cut -f 12 -d '|' tt_id_2014.txt | grep -c 1.  If you can edit your answer since this is slightly more concise, I will accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @AN6U5 I do not like to mix piping and file reading as it is hard for me to read. This is especially true with the pipe as the deliminator. I think my answer is much easier to read (despite the extra characters and possibly slight inefficiency).

Comment: Okay, that's fine.  Another issue is that grep -c 1 counts all 1's where as I only want to count the first 1 after the 12th pipe, so it should be grep -c '^1'

Comment: @AN6U5 or possibly you want '^1$', as '^`' will match 11. It is hard to tell from your question what you want.

Comment: If you like piping the file with cat in order to have the file name in the pipeline's beginning, you can rewrite the command with redirection as follows:
<myfile.txt cut -d '|' -f 12 | grep -c 1

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' '$13 ~ /^1/{count++} END{print count}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Single `grep` with `-P`erl compatible option:

```
grep -Pc '^([^\|]*\|){12}\K1' file
```